# How to debug browser tab history in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser, back-button, browser-history

I'm trying to debug a website in which the back button history behaves strangely. To do this, I want to inspect what the history contains.

I can hold the back button:

[image]

But this shows only page titles, I also want to see the URLs.

I can inspect `window.history` after pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> (in my case, this shows Firebug), but this only tells me how many items does the history contain, nothing else.

So, how can I see what does the tab history contain? I want to know the page title and the URL (and possibly other information, if available) for each history entry. The behavior I'm trying to debug seems to only affect Firefox, so I need a solution that can used there.

Answer (score 1):

With the add-on Backward/Forward History Tweak you can modify the default behaviour of a tab's backward history menu, with for instance an option to display both the title and the URL of each page, or URL only and title when hovering, or whatever you need (and also set the number of items displayed, add a number, sort in ascending or descending order...). It's one of my favorite add-ons for FF.
Another add-on which may be useful in this case : Session History Tree, but I haven't used it lately.
Otherwise, you can load the sessionstore.js (or recovery.js in the sessionstore-backups folder) in a text editor and find all stored URLs, for each tab/window, amidst a lot of extra stuff, so it might be tedious to find what you're looking for. Perhaps there is another add-on or standalone program which can parse that file and provide a more streamlined output.